# My external javascript file is being read as a json file

Tags: javascript

In the network tab of the developers tools, my external javascript file is being read as a json file instead even though it is saved as javascript. I am not sure how to go about fixing this.

EDIT:

[image: Screenshot]

Don't have enough rep to post images here, but the link to the left shows that my file is saved as a javascript but the file type says json.

EDIT #2:

[image: code used to load the file]

```
function hello(){
 alert("Hello, World");
}
```

just trying to use that lil bit of code to try to get the file itself to work.

EDIT #3:
So i changed the src path as mentioned by user onetwo12 said but the file is still getting a 404 error.

Comment: It says *404 not found* so the file type doesn't really matter. Also, you haven't provided any [mcve] showing how you are trying to load it.

Comment: Can you post the content of `app.js`?

Comment: The content of `app.js` is less important than the code that attempts to load it or simply getting the URL to it right in your code.

Comment: the second photo shows how i'm injecting the file and the file paths in my project

Comment: You cannot get `app.js` like that from `index.html` your path is wrong. Change the path `src="js\app.js"`.

Comment: It means that your path is still wrong, try something like `../../js/app.js` you should be able to see from Network Tab in which path it is trying to locate the `app.js` file and try to write the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks for your guy's help but after looking where the css files were at, it looks like the scripts and anything else I make will be called from the static directory first and then into whatever I call in the src. So i moved the js directory from outside static directory into the static directory and got things working.